# Finding average output in Java

Tags: java, output

I am trying to figure out how to find the average output - not the running time - of the method below. The question I am supposed to be able to answer is what is wrong with using this method to determine the average of a rolled die. I am thinking average is going to require a double and not an int to be returned so that is the problem, but am I missing anything else?

```
public static int dieSquared(){
    Die die = new Die ();
    die.roll()
    return die.getTopFace() * die.getTopFace();
}
```

Comment: I think we need the Die class too.

Comment: Since you're obviously posting a homework problem on SO, post the whole problem. It looks like you're misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: @Kayaman I am not sure I understand what you mean. If I roll a die 6 times and get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 for a total of 21, the average would be 3.5. Int cannot return decimals. So I am not sure if this is what the question is asking or what. It is very vague.

Comment: average and squares are not related, unless you are perhaps doing something else.  die.roll() is missing a semicolon, and I don't understand why you are declaring this a static method.  Math.pow(die.getTopFace(), 2) can also square your number.

Comment: @uvesten The question states verbatim: We might want to know the average output (not running time) of the method above. We might try to do this by determining the average result of rolling a die and then squaring that. What is wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: @ergonaut I have never used squaring to obtain any average for anything so the squaring would not return an average. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Here's an example why it does not work for finding the average. It has nothing to do with ints or floats. 

5^2+3^2+2^2 = 6^2+1^2+1^2

Comment: @uvesten I am not sure I see the correlation.

Comment: @AdamicBombs then think a bit more... using the function, both those series of throws sum up to 38.

Comment: @uvesten right. But what does that have to do with averaging? All we did was square the results...

Comment: The average die roll value is `(1+2+3+4+5+6)/6 = 3.5` so the squared value would be `3.5 * 3.5 = 12.25`. The average value of this method is `(1*1+2*2+3*3+4*4+5*5+6*6)/6 = 15.16`. So both values are not the same, since the order of operation matters.

Comment: So in other words, I was completely over complicating the thought process... Wow... Thanks all.